# kivy endless while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, kivy

i'm a new begginer to python and kivy, and recently i was trying to make a learning application to work and i don't know how to make it running without stoping ? this is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from random import randrange
import time


#verbs and answers
verbs = ["arise", "awake", "be", "bear", "beat", "become", "begin", "bend", "bet", "bind", "bite", "bleed", "blow", "break", "breed", "bring", "broadcast", "build", "burn", "burst"]
answers =["arose", "awoke", "was", "bore", "beat", "became", "began", "bent", "bet", "bound", "bit", "bled", "blew", "broke", "bred", "brought", "broadcast", "built", "burnt", "burst"]
range = 20


    


rand = randrange(0, range)




class english_learning(App):
    
    def build(self):


        


        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
            

        self.window.add_widget(Image(source='cat.png'))

        self.greeting = Label(text=verbs[rand])
        self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)




        self.answer = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.window.add_widget(self.answer)

        self.button = Button(text="check")
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.check_answer)
        
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)
        return self.window
    def check_answer(self, instance):

        if self.answer.text == answers[rand]:
            self.greeting.text = 'yes!' + self.answer.text + ' is the correct verb'

        else:
            self.greeting.text = "no!"


        

        


        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    english_learning().run()
```

the app is asking for a verb and then check it if it is correct or not but it is working one time.
how can i add while loop to make it asking for a answer every time and checking if it is correct or not please ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already sticking around forever, right?  The only issue is that it only chooses one word, and sticks with that word forever.  So, when they guess correctly, choose another word:

```
    def check_answer(self, instance):
        global rand
        if self.answer.text == answers[rand]:
            rand = randrange(0,range)
            self.greeting.text = 'yes!' + self.answer.text + ' is the correct verb\n\nNow try: " + verb[rand]
        else:
            self.greeting.text = "no!"
```

Now, rather than use a global for this, it would be better to store this in a class variable:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from random import randrange
import time


#verbs and answers
verbs = ["arise", "awake", "be", "bear", "beat", "become", "begin", "bend", "bet", "bind", "bite", "bleed", "blow", "break", "breed", "bring", "broadcast", "build", "burn", "burst"]
answers =["arose", "awoke", "was", "bore", "beat", "became", "began", "bent", "bet", "bound", "bit", "bled", "blew", "broke", "bred", "brought", "broadcast", "built", "burnt", "burst"]
range = 20



class english_learning(App):
    def build(self):
        self.target = randrange(0, range)

        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.window.add_widget(Image(source='cat.png'))

        self.greeting = Label(text=verbs[self.target])
        self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)

        self.answer = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.window.add_widget(self.answer)

        self.button = Button(text="check")
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.check_answer)
        
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)
        return self.window

    def check_answer(self, instance):

        if self.answer.text == answers[self.target]:
            self.target = randrange(0, range)
            self.greeting.text = 'yes!' + self.answer.text + ' is the correct verb\n\nNow try:' + verbs[self.target]
        else:
            self.greeting.text = "no!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    english_learning().run()
```

Really, you probably want a separate line for the "verb" and the "greeting".